# Select columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with hundreds of columns of antibiotic names. Each specific antibiotic is coded in the dataframe as ending in E, T, or P to indicate empirical, treatment, or prophylactic regimens.

An example excerpt from the column list is:

> ['MeropenemP', 'MeropenemE', 'MeropenemT', DoripenemP', 'DoripenemE',
>   'DoripenemT', ImipenemP', 'ImipenemE', 'ImipenemT', 'BiapenemP',
>   'BiapenemE', 'BiapenemT', 'PanipenemP', 'PanipenemE',
>   'PanipenemT','PipTazP', 'PipTazE', 'PipTazT','PiperacillinP',
>   'PiperacillinE', 'PiperacillinT']

A small sample of data is located here:

[Sample antibiotic data](https://github.com/johnmarquess/some.data/blob/master/ABX_data.csv)

It is simple enough for me to separate out columns any type into separate dataframes with a regex, e.g. to select all the empirically prescribed antibiotics columns I use:

```
E_cols = master.filter(axis=1, regex=('[a-z]+E$'))
```

Each column has a binary value (0,1) for prescription of each antibiotic regimen type per person (row).

**Question:**
How would I go about summing **the rows** of all columns (1's) for each type of regimen type and generating a new column for each result in the dataframe e.g. total_emperical, total_prophylactic, total_treatment.

The reason I want to add to the existing dataframe is that I wish to filter on other values for each regimen type.

Comment: You should be able to just do `df['total_emperical'] = df[E_cols].sum()` and repeat for the other types

Comment: thanks @EdChum - I edited my question for clarity. I want to sum the rows for each regimen type and put them in a new column.

Comment: If you pass param `axis=1` to `sum` it will will sum row-wise

Comment: @EdChum sometimes the solution seems so easy it makes me want to kick myself for not thinking just a little harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've generated the list of columns that match your reg exp then you can just create the new total columns like so:

```
df['total_emperical'] = df[E_cols].sum(axis=1)
```

and repeat for the other totals.

Passing `axis=1` to [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) will sum row-wise